# Convert a list of JToken to a list of one of the values

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a list of json JTokens:

```
List<JToken> subjectresults = jObj[jp]["subjects"].Children().ToList();
```

Note that my jp is `var jp = jObj.Properties().First().Name;` because the name is dynamic.

Each of the tokens contains two further items, a url and a name.
I want to get a list of strings that contains just the name value, from this list of jtokens.

So that:

```
[0]: {{
  "url": "https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science",
  "name": "Science"
}}

    [1]: {{
  "url": "https://openlibrary.org/subjects/in_library",
  "name": "In library"
}}
```

Becomes:

```
{"Science", "In library"}
```

I can't seem to figure out the syntax.
Or alternatively how do I skip the tokens and go right to my list. 
I didn't strongly type this, because the parent property has the dynamic name, and I only needed a couple of the fields.

Comment: The input JSON sample in your question isn't well-formed.  Can you please share the actual JSON, instead of some visualization?  (`{"Science", "In library"}` isn't well-formed JSON either, but perhaps that isn't supposed to be JSON, but just some list of strings?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that *subjects*-property is *Array*:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

var jp = jObj.Properties().First().Name;
var subjectresults = jObj[jp]["subjects"]
    .Children()
    .Select(v => v["name"].Value<string>())
    .ToArray();

/*
subjectresults
{string[2]}
[0] [string]:"Science"
[1] [string]:"In library"
*/
```

The source json:

```
var json = @"{
        ""name"": {
            ""subjects"": [
                {
                    ""url"": ""https://openlibrary.org/subjects/science"",
                    ""name"": ""Science""
                },
                {
                    ""url"": ""https://openlibrary.org/subjects/in_library"",
                    ""name"": ""In library""
                }
            ]
        }                
    }";
```